# localhost, Cross-Origin Request Blocked , CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

There is a jar file random_file.jar , which will produce output to a URL like , `http://localhost:8010/statistics` in XML format , the client UI program need to read the data and plot it as graph.

While making ajax call, it throws error as,  `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8010/statistics . (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).` below is the ajax call;

```
    var url= 'http://localhost:8010/statistics ';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        crossOrigin: true,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "xml",
        accept: 'application/xml'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.write(data);                
    })
```

though client UI program running in local web server, the ajax call fails with CORS error, please suggest.

Comment: Are you using WordPress ???

Comment: no , both the server and client are in localhost, using java and jquery respectively .

Comment: Are you really using `<port>` in your request???

Comment: the server is listening  in 8010, and the client is in jetty with port 8080.

Comment: So there you have it. It is only considered to be the same if the protocol + host + port is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request origin is only considered the same if protocol + host + port are equal.
You can try fixing it by using the [Jetty CORS Filter](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/cross-origin-filter.html) (configurable in web.xml) or by using a proxy.